# setTimeout() triggering without delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, ext.net

I have the following code

```
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            setTimeout(everything(), 30000);
        });
```

I am trying to wait for EXT.NET to completely finish compiling the page before applying any javascript to the elemtents. This is not a problem in most browsers as $(document).load provides enough of delay. Of course the horrid internet explorer triggers .load prematurely which means I have to put in a hard coded delay in. The above code however, does NOTHING to delay the execution of everything().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `()` from `everything`

```
setTimeout(everything, 30000);
```

By including `()`, you are telling the browser to immediately execute `everything` and send it's return value as the callback function to the `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
setTimeout(everything(), 30000);
```

to

```
setTimeout("everything()", 30000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(everything, 30000);
```

Comment: it is much preferable to pass by reference, fyi

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted, you should be writing this instead:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  setTimeout(everything, 30000);
});
```

What they haven't posted is an explanation. In the above snippet, `everything` is a reference to a function within the scope that called the `Ext.onReady()` method. In your question, you are using `setTimeout()` to execute the result of the `everything()` function. It's likely that your `everything()` function returns `undefined`, so your `setTimeout()` call never does anything.

Someone suggested using `setTimeout("everything()", 30000)`. This is [effectively the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3445884/7979) as using `eval()`. Thus, this is not a recommended approach.