# Why JavaScript alerts allways 4 in when for-loop is for 3?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why this JavaScript alerts allways 4 in when for-loop is for 3?

```
// alert
function reOrderLayers(layerToaAlter) {
alert(layerToaAlter);
}

// prepare
var laCount;
for (laCount = 1; laCount <= 3; laCount++) {
    var la = document.getElementById("layerChanger"+laCount);
    la.addEventListener("click", function () { reOrderLayers(laCount) });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6425062/783219 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3445855/783219

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loop is finished means `i` is `>3`, to preserve particular number in function call use closures:

```
  la.addEventListener("click", (function(count) { return function () { reOrderLayers(count) } })(laCount)  );
```

Answer (score 2):

The for loop continues until `laCount == 4` (the last time the loop is executed the value is 3 and then it is incremented to 4 so that the loop test fails). Therefore the value is 4 after the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you click on the element; for loop is already finished and current value of laCount  would be 4;

you should create a context to save laCount for each layerChanger:

```
function reOrderLayers(layerToaAlter) {
   alert(layerToaAlter);
}
function context(la, laCount){

         la.addEventListener("click", function () { reOrderLayers(laCount) });
  }

// prepare
var laCount, la;
for (laCount = 1; laCount <= 3; laCount++) {
    la = document.getElementById("layerChanger"+laCount);
    context(la, laCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call `reOrderLayers` immediately in the loop but constructed a function literal. The literal will have a closure and it refers to the `laCount` variable in the environment which will be 4 when the click event is eventually fired.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

```
var c = 0;
for(c = 1; c <= 3; c++) {};
alert(c); // alerts 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

During the first 3 iterations the `for` loop goes into the body and conducts the code you have inside. Once you're on the 4th iteration, `lacount` get incremented and the condition fails, so that you don't go into the loop again.

If you needed `lacount` to be `3` for some reason, you could try setting the initial for loop condition to `i < 3`.