# How best to deal with looping and addEventListeners?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

My previous question - [Why JavaScript alerts allways 4 in when for-loop is for 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414271/why-javascript-alerts-allways-4-in-when-for-loop-is-for-3/12414357#12414357) - shows that its extremly difficult to catch up with for-loops in JS for addEventListeners, so I came with a brute solution... How can I proper loop it **and** keep it easy to read for newbie?

```
document.getElementById('layerChangerOryginal').addEventListener('click', function() { Layer1() });
document.getElementById('layerChanger1').addEventListener('click', function() { Layer1() });
document.getElementById('layerChanger2').addEventListener('click', function() { Layer2() });
document.getElementById('layerChanger3').addEventListener('click', function() { Layer3() });

function Layer1() {
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer1').className='container layer1';
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer2').className='container layer2';
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer3').className='container layer3';
}
function Layer2() {
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer1').className='container layer3';
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer2').className='container layer1';
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer3').className='container layer2';
}
function Layer3() {
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer1').className='container layer3';
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer2').className='container layer2';
    document.getElementById('oryginalLayer3').className='container layer1';
}
```

Comment: It's hard to get for me. The best understanding for me is going to be when I showed you simple code Its working and ask how to improve it.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the solutions from your earlier question? I know closures are not easy for newbies, but if you're going to do much Javascript you need to learn about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  document.getElementById('layerChanger'+i).addEventListener('click', window['Layer'+i]);
}
```

This works because any top-level function or variable named `name` is the value of `window[name]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using loops:

```
var a, i, j,
    eventFunc, 
    args_list = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]],

    str1 = 'container layer',
    str2 = 'oryginalLayer',
    byId = function(x) {
        return document.getElementById(x);
    };


for (i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
    eventFunc = function() {
        for (j = 1; j < 4; ++j) {
            byId(str2 + j).className = str1 + args_list[i][j];
        }
    };

    byId('layerChanger' + i).addEventListener('click', eventFunc, false);

    if (i === 1) {
        byId('layerChangerOryginal').addEventListener('click', eventFunc, false);
        ++i;
    }
}​
```

Seems a little bit more complicated than the equivalent code below:

```
var str = 'container layer',
    byId = function (x) {
        return document.getElementById(x);
    },

    createLayerFunc = function ( a, b, c ) {
        return function LayerX(x) {
            byId('oryginalLayer1').className = str+a;
            byId('oryginalLayer2').className = str+b;
            byId('oryginalLayer3').className = str+c;
        };
    },

    Layer1 = createLayerFunc(1, 2, 3),
    Layer2 = createLayerFunc(3, 1, 2),
    Layer3 = createLayerFunc(3, 2, 1);


byId('layerChangerOryginal').addEventListener('click', Layer1, false);
byId('layerChanger1').addEventListener('click', Layer1, false);
byId('layerChanger2').addEventListener('click', Layer2, false);
byId('layerChanger3').addEventListener('click', Layer3, false);
```